# Wild card search in SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have ran across a few queries that use this where condition:

```
select ...
where Name like '%'
```

Is there a purpose for using a wildcard like that?

Comment: is it within another clause or by itself?  Is it a way to force a scan?

Comment: If the query is generated in code then it may have been a shortcut to provide a non-filter filter.  It's often more work to omit the `WHERE` clause when it has already been tacked on to a query being built on the fly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`WHERE Name LIKE '%'` is equivalent to `WHERE Name IS NOT NULL` (at least in the tests I ran). The later is perhaps more efficient, and IMO much easier to see the intent of, but I suppose `like '%'` saves few keystrokes. Either way, its not just filler.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not, unles there's some edge case I don't know about with the way a text search is handled. I'd do an experiment to see what it does if Name is null if I were near a MySQL client now.

I've seen some code that uses queries with "...where 1=1" just because it was easier to output a meaningless where clause than to deal with cases where a where clause is absent in generated queries. Or I there used to be a meaningful condition that was removed in some edit.

Comment: `see what it does if Name is null` - it just won't select the row

Comment: Right. So then "Name like '%'" may be equivalent to "Name is not null".